# python selenium execute onscroll javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with a js heavy webpage and I have a `div` element which looks like so:

```
<div id="results-ItemSearch" class="itemresults" onscroll="loadMoreItems(event)">
....
</div>
```

It is one of those webpages which does autoscrolling (further complicated by the fact that there are three panes within the same window and I am having a hard time getting to the pane I want to work with), and normally, I implement something like this in selenium:

```
no_of_pagedowns = 1
while no_of_pagedowns:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(1)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1
```

however, when I do this on this webpage, I get a `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` exception.

I tried selecting by css, but that does not yield anything either. I also tried `waiting` for 15 or so seconds for complete load, but that does not seem to work either.

Thus, I was wondering if there is a way to directly excecute the JS `loadMoreItems(event)` via selenium.

Any help will be appreciated - spent 4 hours on this now!

Comment: Have you tried `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", someElement)`? You could locate the 'last' item inside your `itemresults` list, and scroll to it this way -- this should ideally trigger `loadMoreItems(event)`.

Comment: @Christine: the problem is that I could never see the last element :( anyways, Guy's answer below worked well. Thank you for reading through my question and suggesting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try scrolling with JavaScript

```
element =  browser.find_element_by_id('results-ItemSearch')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight)', element)
```

Or

```
driver.execute_script('scrollBy(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight))', element)
```

Comment: simply put, you are a genius!! The first option worked like a charm. The second, for some reason, did not work. I would have NEVER figured this out without your help. I REALLY appreciate your time. Thank you. Answer accepted.